# Code duplication with subplots of dyinamic size: how to solve it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to save a picture made up of several subplots: the problem is that originally I don't know how many subplots do I need (it depends on `num_plots`) so I want to obtain a function that generates plots differently in different cases:

1. If `num_plots` is 3 or less, make a row of exactly `num_plots` subplots
2. If there's more than 3, generate the required number of lines (each of size 3)

The problem is that I cannot manage to do this without avoiding code duplication. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
def foo(num_plots, ...):
    # ... obtain data to plot ('all_results')
    total_cols = 3 if num_plots > 2 else num_plots
    total_rows = math.ceil(num_plots / total_cols)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=total_rows, ncols=total_cols, figsize=(7 * total_cols, 7 * total_rows),
                            constrained_layout=True)
    for i in range(num_plots):
        row = i // total_cols
        pos = i % total_cols

        # psi_name and psi_value depend on the parameters of the function
    
        if num_plots == 1:
            sns.kdeplot(all_results[:, i], color='magenta', ax=axs)
            axs.hist(all_results[:, i], bins=nbins)
            axs.axvline(x=psi_value, linestyle='--', color='red')
            axs.set_title(f"Estimation test for {psi_name} = {psi_value}")
        elif total_rows == 1:
            sns.kdeplot(all_results[:, i], color='magenta', ax=axs[pos])
            axs[pos].hist(all_results[:, i], bins=nbins)
            axs[pos].axvline(x=psi_value, linestyle='--', color='red')
            axs[pos].set_title(f"Estimation test for {psi_name} = {psi_value}")
        else:
            sns.kdeplot(all_results[:, i], color='magenta', ax=axs[row, pos])
            axs[row, pos].hist(all_results[:, i], bins=nbins)
            axs[row, pos].axvline(x=psi_value, linestyle='--', color='red')
            axs[row, pos].set_title(f"Estimation test for {psi_name} = {psi_value}")
    plt.savefig(token_hex(8))
```

As you can see the problem is that according to the number of plots needed I have to use `axs` or `axs[pos]` or `axs[row, pos]` instead. Notice that simply using `axs[row, pos]` gives me a error. **How can I solve this code duplication problem?**

Here are few examples of plots resulting from this function:

If `num_plots` is 1:

[image: If num_plots is 1]

If `num_plots` is 3:

[image: If num_plots is 3]

If `num_plots` is 4:

[image: If num_plots is 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `add_subplots()` sequential drawing technique work for your purposes? However, it is set up to draw multiple graphs on a single chart, so a single one is maximized by the size of the chart. You will get a warning, but it can be ignored.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20)
cnt = 5
cols = 3
rows = round(cnt / cols,0)

for i in range(cnt):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(rows,cols,i+1)
    ax.plot(x, x**i)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Another small question: the resulting plots feel a little too distant to me, if I try to use `constrained_layout=True` they get too close (overlapping the axis labels). Can you suggest me a way to obtain a closer formation without exaggerating? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `constrained_layout=False` What will happen if I unlock it? Try this if it improves.`fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want constrained layout to work, you can create a gridspec and add to it piecemeal:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9), constrained_layout=True)


x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20)
cnt = 5
cols = 3
rows = round(cnt / cols,0)

gs = fig.add_gridspec(int(rows), int(cols))

for ind in range(cnt):
    i = int(np.floor(ind / cols))
    j = ind % cols

    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, j])
    ax.plot(x, x**ind)

plt.show()
```

Note that future matplotlib 3.4, `add_subplot` as used above will also work with constrained_layout, but it is not released yet: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17347